# PHP - Propel PDO Returns zero rows regardless of query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to execute a query through PDO directly, though I am using Propel as my ORM.  The problem is that the query ALWAYS returns 0 records.  I'm not sure what happen because it was working very nicely last night and then when I got up this morning to work on my project, I have been dealing with this particular problem.

At first, I was trying to return a JOIN query with parameters, which I knew there was qualifying records for.  Then after about an hour thinking it was my params, etc, I switched to using a very simple select statement.

php Code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM league;";
$con = Propel::getConnection();
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

I have tried querying all tables in the database with the same result.  What could be the problem?  I've tried the queries in phpMyAdmin as well as MySQLWorkbench.

After a day and half, I can't figure out what the problem is.  Hopefully someone can help out.

Thanks.

Comment: `;` the semi-colon in your query *could* be causing issues

Comment: You are also forgetting to call `execute()` before `fetchAll()`

Comment: OMG!  Hurray for mental myopia!  I can't believe I missed that.  Quite embarrassing.  Thanks, Monkey.

Comment: Just a quick follow up.  Shouldn't "setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)" have excepted by calling fetchAll() before execute?  Just curious.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes I think, but I do not see your exception handling so I have no clue `what you expected` vs `what you received`

Comment: Is `error_reporting(E_ALL);` declared before you run this PDO block?

Comment: Nope.  I was under the impression that setting $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION) would do that.  Thanks for the follow up, sir.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment is the correct answer: You are forgetting to call execute() before fetchAll()

A working version of the code is:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM league;";
$con = Propel::getConnection();
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(); // <-- This executes the statement, without it, there is no result set to fetch
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
```